# How I draw this Graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqvKA.png)Let $[n] = \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$. Consider G the simple graph whose vertices are the subsets of $[5]$ of cardinality $3$ in which two vertices are adjacent if the intersection of the subsets is a subset of cardinality $2$. Represent Graph $G$

R: The subsets of $[5]$ of cardinality $3$ are given by $5C3 = 10$, so the graph has 10 vertices.These vertices are adjacent if the intersection of the subsets is a subset of cardinality 2. 
Should I make 10C2?How to draw this graph?

Comment: Start out by writing down the vertices. You might try writing the adjacent vertices near one another to get a neat graph.  Anyway, then just draw an edge between each pair of neighbors.  You may want to play around with it afterwards to make it look neater.

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph

Answer (score 1):

The following graph will do the trick.

[image: The Petersen Graph]